# Cannot access beanstalk env variables inside docker for building react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a react app in beanstalk, but am facing an issue with '.env' variables.

I set up all the required env variables in the beanstalk. The react app needs these variables during the building. Since the building occurs inside docker and these variables are not accessible inside docker, I am getting errors.

How can I solve this issue? I cannot add these variables to the code itself. it should be in the beanstalk.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11.10
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN yarn
EXPOSE 8080
run yarn build
CMD [ "yarn", "start"]
```

Also is there any way I can get all these env variables from beanstalk and append it to the code before building?